# Does ICAO require (or suggest) set of technical statuses of radar and its subsystems?

Tags: radar, icao

Does ICAO require (or suggest) set of technical statuses of radar and its subsystems? In other words is it required that radar status can be set to `Normal`, `Warning` and `Error`, or `Idle`, `Alarm`, `Unknown` also possible? There are [002](http://www.eurocontrol.int/sites/default/files/service/content/documents/nm/asterix/cat002-asterix-monoradar-service-messages-part2b.pdf) and [034](http://www.eurocontrol.int/sites/default/files/content/documents/nm/asterix/cat034-asterix-monoradar-service-messages-part-2b-next-version-of-cat-002.pdf) categories of [ASTERIX](https://www.eurocontrol.int/asterix) which describe messages about radar status, but I haven't found out answer on my question.

Comment: Welcome to Aviation.SE Glutton. Where did you find the statuses you mentioned? I can't find them in the ASTERIX specs.

Comment: `Welcome to Aviation.SE`, Thanks! `Where did you find the statuses you mentioned?` I've meant Data Items: I002/050 (Station Configuration Status), I002/080 (Warning/Error Conditions) and I034/050 (System Configuration and Status). But compliance with the requirements of the ASTERIX isn't my purpose, I just try use ASTERIX as a hint for my more general question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These statuses are not defined by nor required explicitly by ICAO.

The details of how a radar (or other surveillance) system communicates with downstream ATC systems are defined in a technical specification documents, typically produced by EUROCAE and/or RTCA.

The ASTERIX specifications are maintained by EUROCONTROL and only give the format in which surveillance ground systems communicate amongst each other. The specifications were originally intended to facilitate surveillance data exchange between European countries, but they have now been adopted by many countries outside Europe.

Category 002 (old) and 034 define the status messages monoradar systems use to update downstream systems (radar trackers, displays) on the radar's status.

Comment: `These statuses are not defined by nor required explicitly by ICAO.`, Thanks this is answer on my question. `technical specification documents, typically produced by EUROCAE and/or RTCA`, Thanks for hint.